# htaccess redirect all to www except IP

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web, ip

All my website page URL's are redirected to have a www at the beginning. So, if someone types http//xyz.com it will automatically make it http//www.xyz.com. This is fine for me. But the main problem is, if someone types 123.234.111.121 it will again put a www at the beginning, which is wrong. How do I fix it? Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

My current setup is as follows

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I even tried with this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^50\.56\.246\.162
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But, it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[0-9]+\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[0-9]+\.` will skip this rule if you supply an IP address to access the website.

Comment: Hi! Anubhava. Thanks for your prompt reply. But it does not work as expected. Please see this 50.56.246.162/svn/7sis_repo Again a www seems to get added before the IP

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Try this in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: Your logic seems to be correct, but I tried in new Browser. For your satisfaction, I cleared all cache. Still this happens :(

Comment: For your satisfaction I again tested this already tested rule and it didn't redirect to `www`

Comment: Also when I tried to visit: `50.56.246.162/svn/7sis_repo` it asked me to enter username/passwd which means there are other rules in it that might be conflicting with this rule.

Answer (score 0):

The above rule as suggested by anubhava is not working for me also. I google around and came with this answer.

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```